# Why does the thermal conductivity of water decrease with increasing salinity?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

Intuitively I would expect the thermal and electric conductivity to be positively related, and since electric conductivity increases with salinity, so should thermal. But according to [this table](http://web.mit.edu/seawater/Seawater_Property_Tables.pdf) (p.10) it decreases. Why is this?

Related: is there such a thing as the Wiedemann-Franz law for liquids like water?

There's a paper that has theoretical derivations about it, but it's nowhere to be found:
`Predvoditelev, A. S., "Some invariant Quantities in the Theories of Heat Conductance and the Viscosity of Liquids," Russian Journal of Physical Chemistry, Vol. 22, p. 339 (1948)`

Comment: Someone correct me, if I am wrong, but doesn't the expectation that thermal conductivity and electrical conductivity are correlated come from the special case of metal physics, where electron transport is the main source of both (in a certain temperature range)? There are marvelous counterexamples, for instance diamond, sapphire and pure crystalline silicon, which have enormous thermal conductivity, but very poor or basically non-existent electrical conductivity.

Comment: @CuriousOne, yes this confuses me also, yet i too have seen cases where the 2 are not correlated as such

Comment: @CuriousOne yes, that is what I based my expectation on. I agree that it's a bit loose to tie metals and saline liquids together like that.

Comment: I completely misread the question. Somehow I read it as asking about specific heat. I'm withdrawing my answer, and then later I'll withdraw this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(add my comment as an answer)

A short answer would be that although [electric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_conductivity) and [thermal conductivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity) have (movement of free) electrons as their primary carriers, they operate on different ranges/frequencies/wavelengths, and as such the [structure and energy zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure) of the material (or material compound) can have quite different factors for each type of conductance.

From the Wikipedia article on thermal conductivity:

> In metals, thermal conductivity approximately tracks electrical
>   conductivity according to the Wiedemann–Franz law, as freely moving
>   valence electrons transfer not only electric current but also heat
>   energy. However, the general correlation between electrical and
>   thermal conductance does not hold for other materials, due to the
>   increased importance of [phonon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonons) [carriers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_scattering#Phonon_Scattering) for heat in non-metals. Highly
>   electrically conductive silver is less thermally conductive than
>   diamond, which is an electrical insulator, but due to its orderly
>   array of atoms it is conductive of heat via [phonons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonons)

Comment: Which field should I look into to learn more about this?

Comment: @PatronBernardm there [various fields](http://physics.about.com/od/physics101thebasics/f/FieldsPhysics.htm) which intersect on this area, like solid-state physics, electromagnetism, thermodynamics